# What is the difference between Temp1 and Core shown in SpeedFan?

Tags: cpu, temperature, speedfan

I am beginning to use [Speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php).

I was wondering what is the difference between Temp1 and Core shown in SpeedFan? Whose temperature is more important?

Comment: I don't know, but I'm guessing the Core temperature is the CPU core, and therefore the most important. However, with most CPUs, they'll shut down the computer before burning out. You'll be better off monitoring the north and south bridge on your board.

Comment: Thanks! What in Speedfan monitors the north and south bridge?

Answer (score 2):

TBH it's difficult to say. My guess would be Temp1 is the temperature returned by the thermal diode sensors just near the heatsink & Core would be the temperature of each core. Both would be critical.  As for northbridge/southbridge temperatures - Speedfan should return them if suitable sensors are available.

Else check out [HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html).

Comment: +1 for HWMonitor, it properly picks up all of my sensors.